# How to execute a block of code if async function errors out

Tags: javascript, async-await

```
const myFunction = async() => {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('https://www.google.com/');

        const performanceTiming = JSON.parse(
            await page.evaluate(() => JSON.stringify(window.performance.timing))
        );
        console.log(performanceTiming);

        await browser.close();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`catch error`, error);
    }
};

(async function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        const result = await myFunction();
        if (result) {
            console.log(`it worked`);
        } else {
            console.log(`Did not work work for iteration #: ${i + 1}, trying again...`);
            i--;
        }
    }
})();
```

`myFunction` is an async function. I am calling it in IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression). Inside IIEF, I am expecting else block to execute only if something goes wrongs. But when I run this, I get console message from `myFunction`; which means nothing went wrong, but else bock is executed and I am getting in an infinite loop. What's wrong am I doing?

Comment: Your `myFunction` never returns any truthy `result`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's wrong am I doing?

You are only executing the `if` block if `result` is a truthy value. But `myFunction` never returns anything, so the return value will always be (a promise that resolves to) `undefined`. You have to return something in the successful case.

Or if it doesn't make sense to return something, let the error bubble up and put the `try...catch` clause inside the loop.